# How do I install Windows Chipset Drivers if the System crashes on boot because of missing chipset drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, chipset

I have a new Mainboard and CPU that comes with a driver CD. I can not boot my old windows 7 system because it crashes instantly upon trying to boot with no time to read what caused the crash. I think I need to install the new chipset drivers before switching the system, but how can I do that when I can not log into the old Windows 7 system to read the DVD and run the driver installation?

Also the old system was not UEFI, the new system is. I would need to reconfigure Windows 7 to support that.

I have no access to the old installation medium as I got it from a now defunct Dreamspark Project.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly scraped from Tom's Hardware, [posted by user PaperDoc](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2233431/install-motherboard-drivers.html#r13799193):

> You've run into a classic problem. You tried to use an existing installed version of Windows (on your HDD) on a different mobo, and that almost always cannot work. The reason is that EVERY Windows is customized when it is first Installed. The process takes a survey of all the hardware in the system and installs all the device drivers needed for it, but no others. If you then place that HDD in a different machine, you have some drivers installed with no such devices, and some drivers missing for the new devices.
>
> There is a solution that works in many cases, but not all. You need your Windows Install CD for this. Place it in your optical drive and turn on, booting immediately into BIOS Setup. Go to the place where you specify the Boot Priority Sequence and make sure you have it set to boot from the optical drive first, and then the HDD. SAVE and Exit to boot from the CD.
>
> Do NOT do a normal Install. Instead, find the option to do a Repair Install. This will do the survey of actual devices present now, then survey the drivers on the HDD. Then it will attempt to fix all the mismatches for you. When it is done, your machine may boot up cleanly, or at least with less problems. When done, remove the Install CD so it can boot from the HDD.
>
> If you can get it to boot, go into Windows Device Manager and look for any yellow caution flags that tell you there is still a problem with a driver. You may have to solve those yourself.

Alternatively, bring up the system on the previous mobo, load the new chipset drivers, and *then* switch mobos.

Comment: So the only way to fix this without the old install medium is to install / upgrade to Win10 (or some Windows I have access to because now our university gifts us free Win10 licenses via Microsoft Imagine).

I tried this already but after booting from the USB Stick with the new Windows Install on it it says it can not load critical drivers and I should make sure I have them installed before continueing to install Win10. Where would I even get these drivers from? How do I let the install script access them? I can choose to load drivers from the optical drive but it does not find any.

Comment: If you have access to the previous, un-upgraded mobo and CPU, bring the system back up on those, then load the drivers into the OS, then upgrade hardware. That's most likely the path of least resistance without the old install media. I can also provide install media for WIN7 provided you have a license code for it.

Comment: I still do, so I will try this next (I hope the disassembled cooler still works fine even though I did not renew the heat-spreading-paste). If that does not work I will try a clean install with a working network connection on a clean disk. If that does not work ... well nothing would o.O

Comment: You won’t be able to upgrade to Windows 10 in its current state.  In place upgrade only works if you launch the install from within Windows